# Group name from logged in user

Tags: magento2, customer-session

I am trying to get the groups of a specific user to use that information for sorting products depending on who is logged in. How do I get the group name of a logged in user? I cannot find any documentation about this.

I am using Magento 2.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the group ID from a customer session.

`\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`

You can use the method `getCustomerGroupId()` from this class.

You can use that to determine your group.

I would recommend using group IDs for this, but you can also get additional group information from:

`\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I already know how to get the group ID of a user, but I am not sure about what to do with that information. Would you fetch the group name with a MySQL query or is there another way? My final goal is to be able to match the group name of a user to a specific attribute of a product to be able to sort out products.

Comment: Pass the group ID into the Service Contract `GroupRepositoryInterface`.  Using the `getById()` method will return an instance of `\Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Group`.  You can get group information from that model.